# R zoo object time series aggregation

Tags: r, aggregate, aggregation, zoo

I have an R zoo object. The zoo object (z) is indexed by date and has multiple columns:

- V1 (aggregate value is the sum of all values in 'selected' rows)
- V2 (aggregate value is q1 [first quartile] of all values in 'selected' rows)
- V3 (aggregate value is the minima of all values in 'selected' rows)
- V4 (aggregate value is the first value of all values in 'selected' rows)
- v5 (aggregate value is the last value of all values in 'selected' rows)

I want to aggregate the data in each 'column' differently (i.e. using different functions), but aggregating over the same number of rows.

I want to aggregate using a function that allows me to specify the number of rows over which to aggregate. For example:

```
my_aggregate <- function(data, agg_rowcount) {
  # aggregate data over [agg_rowcount] rows....
  return (aggregated_data)
}
```

I initially thought of implementing this function by using the aptly named aggregate() function - but I could not get it to do what I wanted.

A simple example explaining the error I was getting using aggregate() is follows:

```
> indices <- seq.Date(as.Date('2000-01-01'),as.Date('2000-01-30'),by="day")
> a <- zoo(rnorm(30), order.by=indices)
> b <- zoo(rnorm(30), order.by=indices)
> c <- zoo(rnorm(30), order.by=indices)
> d <- merge(a,b)
> e <- merge(d,c)
> head(e)
                     a          b           c
2000-01-01 -0.07924078  0.6208785 -1.79826472
2000-01-02  1.15956208  1.1867218 -0.02124817
2000-01-03  0.20427523  0.3164863 -0.20153631
2000-01-04  1.21583902 -1.3728278  1.75872854
2000-01-05 -0.32845708  0.3857658 -1.01082787
2000-01-06 -1.95312879 -0.3824591 -1.33220075
>
> aggregate(e,by=e[[1]], nfrequency=8)
Error: length(time(x)) == length(by[[1]]) is not TRUE
```

So I failed at the very first hurdle. I would appreciate any help in helping me write the function that allows me to aggregate different columns differently, accross the same number of rows.

**Note:** I am only into my first few days of 'messing around' with R. For all I know,  aggregate() may not be the way to solve this problem - I don't want the snippet of the code above to be a red herring, and receive answers on how to fix the problem I was getting when using the aggregate function - IF aggregate() is not the "best" (i.e. recommended R) way to approach this problem.

The only reasons why I included my attempt above are:

1. Because I was asked to post a 'reproducable' error
2. To show that I had tried to solve it myself first, before asking in here.

Comment: Please provide something reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we wish to aggregate `e` by week, `w`, aggregating column `a` using `sum`, `b` using `mean` and `c` using the last value in the week:

```
w <- as.numeric(format(time(e), "%W"))
e.w <- with(e, cbind(a = aggregate(a, w, sum), 
    b = aggregate(b, w, mean), 
    c = aggregate(c, w, tail, 1)
))
```

Comment: @GGrothendiek: This is *exactly* how I was thinking of proceeding ... it's good to know I was on the right track. One last thing though is that I want to aggregate by days, where I pass the number of days as a positive integer to the function. It is not clear to me, how I may modify your snippet, to do do this. Could you please show how I can aggregate over a number instead of a string representation (e.g. 7 instead of "W")?. Thanks

Comment: See `nextfri` in `http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf`

Comment: @GGrothendiek: I may be missing somethink here... I looked at the nextfri function. I can see how it may be used for DOW aggregation, but I can't see how it can be used to aggregate over number of rows (i.e. irrespective of day of the week). For example, if I wanted to aggregate the data over 3 days, I am not sure how the nextfri example helps.

Comment: @Homunculus, If you are looking for the sum/mean/tail of all Sundays in your data set, then a second row for the sum/mean/tail of all Mondays and so on then replace `%W` with `%w`.

Comment: @GGrothendiek: My aggregation logic is DOW (day of the week) agnostic. It aggregates based on the number of rows specified - and dosen't care about the day of the week. The data is afterall irregular, so certain days may be missing from the data. All I want to do is to be able to summarize (i.e. aggregate) the data based on an interval which specifies the number of days over which the data is to be aggregated.

Comment: Try: `rollapply(e, 7, by = 7, by.column = FALSE, FUN = function(x) c(a = sum(x[,1]), b = mean(x[,2]), c = tail(x[,3], 1)))` which aggregates each successive set of 7 non-overlapping rows in the data . If this is still not what you want please provide a detailed explanation.

Comment: @GGrothendiek:Am I right in assuming that by replacing 7 with a positive integer m (such tham m < N, where N is the number of rows in the zoo object being aggregated), the aggregation will be carried out over m rows?. If my assumption is correct, then this is exactly what I'm looking to do, and I'll accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: Yes, replace both occurrences of 7.  Try it on a simple object with different values of `k` to verify your understanding: ` k <- 7; z <- zoo(-seq(14)); rollapply(z, k, by = k, FUN = sum)` .

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the ddply function in the plyr package help here?

To aggregate by more than one column:

```
names(e)[1] = 'group'
agg = ddply(e, c("group"), function(df) { 
    c( sum(df$a), mean(df$b), tail(df$c) ) 
})
names(agg) = c('group', 'a', 'b', 'c')
```